# Microeconomics (quasi-linear utility function)

Tags: economics

Suppose that Sally’s preferences over baskets containing food (good x), and clothing (good y), are described by the utility function
$U(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+y$.

Sally’s corresponding marginal utilities are,

$U^\prime_x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$   and    $U^\prime_y=1$.

Use Px to represent the price of food, Py to represent the price of clothing, and I to represent Sally’s income.

> > Question 1: Find Sally's food demand function, and Sally's clothing demand function.
> >     For the purposes of this question you should assume that I/Py **greater than or equal**  Py/4Px.

Clothing demand function : y= I/py - Py/4Px

Food demand function : x = P^2y/4P^2x

After deriving demand function for both Clothing and Food, the following  question confused me.

> Question 3: Now assume that I/Py **less than** Py/4Px. Find Sally's food demand function, and
>   Sally's clothing demand function.

How do i get about doing this following question and getting the **NEW Demand function for Food and Clothing?**

I do know it might  possible be a corner solution.. But how do i explain it in terms of the function as i am not given the price of food and price of clothing in numerical form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a case of optimisation under inequality constraints, where the requirement $x,y \ge 0$ is not stated explicitly. Here is an answer in the language used for your question.

The demand functions are $x^*(p_x,p_y;I) = \dfrac{I}{p_x}$ and $y^*(p_x,p_y;I) = 0$.

Here is a proof. By the rule of weighted marginal utilities, at the margin it is better to purchase $x$ than $y$ whenever 
$$\frac{U^\prime_x}{p_x} \ge \frac{U^\prime_y}{p_y}$$
Substituting for $U^\prime_x$ and $U^\prime_y$ yields
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x^*}}\frac{1}{p_x} \ge \frac{1}{p_y}$$
Replacing $x^* = I/p_x$, we get
$$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{Ip_x}} \ge \frac{1}{p_y}$$
Rearranging, this is precisely the condition $4IP_x \le p_y^2$. When this latter holds, it is always better to purchase $x$ rather than $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the above explanation. I do understand what you meant. But for Question 3, it ask to find Sally's Food Demand Function and Sally's clothing demand function if we assume that now is I/Py < Py/4Px

Wouldn't good y(Clothing) be Zero? How do i show it in a demand function of good y(Clothing)